# When Thranduil mentions his knowledge of the 'fire drakes of the North' is he talking about a battle with Glaurung or Ancalagon?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, dragons

In the movie [Hobbit, The Desolation of Smaug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hobbit%3a_The_Desolation_of_Smaug), the band are captured by [Silvan Elves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silvan_Elves) and taken to [Thranduil's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thranduil) [Castle](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Thranduil) in [Mirkwood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirkwood).

Thranduil confronts [Thorin](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Thorin_II_Oakenshield) and says, "I too have battled the [fire-drakes](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Fire-drakes) of the North." In this scene we temporarily see Thranduil's face [appear with one eye blind and his cheek missing](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Thranduil#The_Hobbit_film_trilogy).

My question is: **Is Thranduil referring to a specific battle with a specific Dragon mentioned in the LoTR, Silmarillion or other letters? Is it [Glaurung](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Glaurung) or [Ancalagon](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Ancalagon)?**