# Which dragon did hurt Thranduil?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit, elves, dragons

When Thorin and Thranduil discuss in Mirkwood, Thranduil said: ''Do not talk to me about the dragon fire. I know what's rage and ruin!'', and shows Thorin his destroyed face for a moment, then says: ''I have faced the great snakes from the north.'' Which dragons did hurt him and when?

Comment: See this [question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47305) too...

Comment: Minor correction - the line is "Do not talk to me of the dragon's fire! I know its rage and ruin."

Comment: Read "The Hobbit" carefully, and you'll discover that this conversation did not happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thranduil would also be very old, a survivor of Doriath in the First Age during the War of Wrath where a lot of dragons (named and unnamed) seen action. So presumably it was there where he encountered the dragon that scared him.

Depending on how you do the math it was roughly 6,000 years between the events of the Hobbit and the War of Wrath if I'm not mistaken. That's a long time for him to encounter something.

Comment: You may want to add that this scene didn't exist in the book and there is no evidence in the books that Thranduil ever faced a dragon.